# "The setup of CorePrint-B647 has failed"

Tags: bluetooth, printing

Got one of those "Chinese Special" bluetooth thermal printers that connect to your mobile phone (in this case, branded "Core Innovations" and a model "CTP500TD"). It's, actually pretty cool! Nice gift actually!

The entire software stack on both the device itself and my iPhone work good. It connects successfully, and prints fine.

But, connecting it to my LG VX10000 out of curiosity, the phone reported that the printer is (essentially) a serial port. Oh! The plot thickens!

So I pulled out my linux laptop, and tried pairing the two. No dice. The builtin bluetooth wizard in KDE Plasma errors out with "The setup of CorePrint-B647 has failed".

It's not the end of the world if I can't connect it up to a "proper" computer, but if I could, that would be nice!

I'm thinking what's happening is that the firmware on the printer is expecting some sort of "challenge response" from whatever tries to connect, ensuring only the app is the one that can connect.

Why? Well, if it's just a bluetooth serial port, even the LG VX10000 (which runs Qualcomm BREW) would have stayed connected with the printer (that phone SUPPORTS serial devices in it's bluetooth services!). My iPhone just goes "Not supported mate. Nuh, not gonna do it" in a stereotypical British accent. No luck under modern Android via the settings app.